# Skip some lines with fread

Tags: r, fread

I am interested to skip some lines of my data frame before the header names . How can i do it by skiping all the lines before `ID_REF` or if `ID_REF` is not present, check for the pattern `ILMN_` and deleting all the lines keeping immediate first if not containing `#`.

```
# GEOarchive matrix file.               
ID_REF  1688628068_A.AVG_Signal 1688628068_A.Avg_NBEADS 1688628068_A.BEAD_STDERR 1688628068_A.Detection Pval
ILMN_1343291    62821.84         135                               413.9399                       0
ILMN_1343292    3255.167         131                               47.76587                       0
ILMN_1343293    42924.91         152                               539.3026                       0
ILMN_1343294    55255.21         100                               746.1457                       0
```

Comment: Looks like you have more column names than columns. Is `1688628068_A.Detection Pval` a single column?.  also if the file have `#` that needs to be skipped, just `read.table('yourfile.txt', header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)` should read it.

Comment: @akrun Yes that is  a single column

Comment: One option is to change the column name in the file to `1688628068_A.Detection_Pval` and read without `fill=TRUE`

Comment: If you have other lines without `#`, another option is to pipe with `awk`,, ie. `read.table(pipe("awk '/^(ID_REF|ILMN)/{ matched = 1} matched { print }' file.txt"), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)

Comment: If i want to read the file from a path, can i use `read.table(path)`

Comment: You may need to paste the path within the awk i.e. replace `file.txt` with your path string

Comment: Thanks,If you don't mind, an example will be helpful.

Comment: I already pasted the code above in the comments `read.table(pipe("awk '/^(ID_REF|ILMN)/{ matched = 1} matched { print }' file.txt"), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)`

Comment: should it be like this `read.table(pipe("awk '/^(ID_REF|ILMN)/{ matched = 1} matched { print }' path1"), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)`,  gives `no lines available in input`

Comment: Is the original file fixed width or tab-delimited?

Comment: @NickK , It is a tab-delimited

Comment: @Hashim fread should just work then with its default options which jump to line 100 and then work backwards to find a line with fewer fields. Read the help on the autostart option (on by default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In linux, you could use `awk` with `fread` or it can be piped with `read.table`.  Here, I changed the delimiter to `,` using `awk`

```
pth <- '/home/akrun/file.txt' #change it to your path
v1 <- sprintf("awk '/^(ID_REF|LMN)/{ matched = 1} matched {$1=$1; print}' OFS=\",\" %s", pth)
```

and read with `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(v1)
#         ID_REF 1688628068_A.AVG_Signal 1688628068_A.Avg_NBEADS
#1: ILMN_1343291               62821.840                     135
#2: ILMN_1343292                3255.167                     131
#3: ILMN_1343293               42924.910                     152
#4: ILMN_1343294               55255.210                     100
#   1688628068_A.BEAD_STDERR 1688628068_A.Detection_Pval
#1:                413.93990                           0
#2:                 47.76587                           0
#3:                539.30260                           0
#4:                746.14570                           0
```

Or using `read.table`

```
read.table(pipe(v1), header=TRUE, sep=',', check.names=FALSE)
#       ID_REF 1688628068_A.AVG_Signal 1688628068_A.Avg_NBEADS
#1 ILMN_1343291               62821.840                     135
#2 ILMN_1343292                3255.167                     131
#3 ILMN_1343293               42924.910                     152
#4 ILMN_1343294               55255.210                     100
#  1688628068_A.BEAD_STDERR 1688628068_A.Detection_Pval
#1                413.93990                           0
#2                 47.76587                           0
#3                539.30260                           0
#4                746.14570                           0
```

NOTE: I changed the column name from `1688628068_A.Detection Pval` to `1688628068_A.Detection_Pval`

For some reason, the extra spaces is creating problems with `fread`.  With `read.table` it is not an issue.  So, the following also works fine with `read.table`

```
 v2 <- sprintf("awk '/^(ID_REF|ILMN)/{ matched = 1} matched { print}' %s", pth)

 read.table(pipe(v2), header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
 #       ID_REF 1688628068_A.AVG_Signal 1688628068_A.Avg_NBEADS
 #1 ILMN_1343291               62821.840                     135
 #2 ILMN_1343292                3255.167                     131
 #3 ILMN_1343293               42924.910                     152
 #4 ILMN_1343294               55255.210                     100
 #  1688628068_A.BEAD_STDERR 1688628068_A.Detection_Pval
 #1                413.93990                           0
 #2                 47.76587                           0
 #3                539.30260                           0
 #4                746.14570                           0
```